# GetThreadContext returning error 6, Invalid Handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, getlasterror

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << "1." << GetLastError() << endl;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo = {0};
    CONTEXT context;

    context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;

    cout << "3." << GetLastError() << endl;

    if (CreateProcess((PCHAR)"rsclient.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo) == false) {
        cout << "CreateProcess error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    cout << "4." << GetLastError() << endl;

    if (GetThreadContext(processInfo.hProcess, &context) == false) {
        cout << "GetThreadContext error:" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1.2
3.2
4.1813
GetThreadContext error:6
```

I can see the suspended process in task manager yet I'm getting an invalid handle error?

Also why does GetLastError() give an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND at the start of the program?

Comment: Only use GetLastError() when you got a failure return code from a Windows function.  GetThreadState() requires a thread handle, not a process handle.

Comment: @HansPassant: Type safety seems like a treat now eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `processInfo.hThread` as that is the handle to the primary thread of the new process. `processInfo.hProcess` is a process handle, not a thread handle.

As for `GetLastError()` returning `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, presumably someone else called an API that called `SetLastError(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`. From the documentation of [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ### Return value
>
> The return value is the calling thread's last-error code.
>
> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that
>   sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function
>   sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's
>   last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also
>   set the last-error code when they succeed. If the function is not
>   documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this
>   function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set;
>   some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do
>   not.

Answer (score -1):

As you are calling GetThreadContext with process id as input, so Windows is not able to find any such kind of thread, so returning ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Better you give the main thread of newly created process and you will get the desired result.